# Error when import war in eclipse ubuntu

Tags: eclipse, ubuntu, jar, war

I want to import a war inside eclipse on ubuntu 16.04 lts machine.
After that i import war, click on next, and then it shows to me:

```
War import: Web libraries

Select the web library jars from the list below to be imported as web library projects.  Unselected web libraries will be imported as jars in the WEB-INF/lib
```

with a list of all jar files that i have under WEB-INF/lib in my project.
The problem is, even if i click on select or unselect all, i can't go on.. i can't click on next/finish.

How can i solve the problem?